# Error when trying to update in react-redux

Tags: react-redux, crud

I am trying to update my data in redux but I get an error when I have more than one value in the state.

How I am transferring data into the AllPalletes component below:

```
<Route exact path='/' render ={(routeProps) => <AllPalletes data = {this.props.palleteNames} />} />
```

**The AllPalletes component, where I am setting up the edit form:**

```
class connectingPalletes extends Component {  

    render () {
        console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <div>
            <Menu inverted>
            <Menu.Item header>Home</Menu.Item>
            <Menu.Item as = {Link} to = '/createpalette'>Create a Palette</Menu.Item>
            </Menu>
            <Container>
            <Card.Group itemsPerRow={4}>
            {this.props.data.map((card) => {
                let cardName = card.Name.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()
                return (
                    <Card key = {card._id}>
                        <Image src = 'https://images.pexels.com/photos/1212406/pexels-photo-1212406.jpeg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&dpr=1&w=500' wrapped ui={false}/>
                        <Card.Content>
                        <Grid>
                        <Grid.Column floated = 'left' width ={7}>
                        {card.edit? (
                            <PaletteEditForm {...card}/>
                        ) : (
                            <Card.Header as = {Link} to = {`/palette/${cardName}`}>{card.Name}</Card.Header>
                        )}

                        </Grid.Column>
                        <Grid.Column floated = 'right' width = {5}>
                        <Icon name = 'pencil' />
                        <Icon name = 'trash' onClick = {() => this.props.dispatch(removePalette({id: card._id}))}/>
                        </Grid.Column>
                        </Grid>
                        </Card.Content>
                        </Card>
                )
            })}
            </Card.Group>
            <Divider></Divider>
            <Divider hidden></Divider>
            <Grid centered columns={1}>
            <Button as = {Link} to = '/testing'>Go Back</Button>
            </Grid>
            </Container>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
const AllPalletes = connect()(connectingPalletes)

export default AllPalletes
```

**And here is the edit form:**

```
class EditForm extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            paletteName: this.props.Name
        }
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        const val = e.target.value,
              s_name = e.target.name
        this.setState (() => {
            return {
                [s_name]: val, 
            }
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = () => {
        let updates = {Name: this.state.paletteName, edit: false}
        this.props.dispatch(editPalette(this.props._id, updates))

    }

    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <Form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmit}>
            <Input type = 'text' name = 'paletteName' value = {this.state.paletteName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
            </Form>

        )
    }
}

const PaletteEditForm = connect()(EditForm)

export default PaletteEditForm
```

**My Reducer:**

```
import uuid from 'uuid/v1'
const paletteDefault = [{
    Name: "Material UI",
    myArray: [],
    _id: uuid(),
    edit: false
}, {
    Name: "Splash UI",
    myArray: [],
    _id: uuid(),
    edit: true
}]

const PaletteReducers = (state = paletteDefault, action) => {
    console.log(action)
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_PALETTE':
            return [...state, action.palette]
            case 'REMOVE_PALETTE':
                return state.filter(x => x._id !== action.id)
                case 'EDIT_PALETTE':
                    return state.map((palette) => {
                        if(palette._id === action.id) {
                            return {
                                ...palette,
                                ...action.updates
                            }
                        }
                    })
        default:
            return state
    }
}

export default PaletteReducers

My Action

// EDIT_PALETTE

const editPalette = (id, updates) => ({
    type: 'EDIT_PALETTE',
    id,
    updates
})

export {addPalette, removePalette, editPalette}
```

I have a feeling that the problem could be in how I have set up the reducer case.

The edit dispatch only works when I have one value in the state. Otherwise, I am getting this error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined
at AllPalletes.js:23
```

Please help..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the error. I had not give a return value in the 'EDIT_PALETTE' case, after the if-statement. It was

```
case 'EDIT_PALETTE':        
return state.map((palette) => {
 if(palette._id === action.id) {
 return {
...palette,
...action.updates
    }
  }
```

})

And instead should be:

```
 case 'EDIT_PALETTE':
return state.map((palette) => {
 if(palette._id === action.id) {
 return {
  ...palette,
  ...action.updates
      }  
     }
  return palette
})
```